# Contact Form 7 - Make DoB field required

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have this code on my contact form to align these elements right.

```
<div id="right">
  e-Mail: [email* email id:email]<br>
  <label>DoB:</label>
  [select* menu-dob-day id:drop_day "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31"] / [select* menu-dob-month id:drop_month "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12"] / [select* menu-dob-year id:drop_year "2000" "1999" "1998" "1997" "1996" "1995" "1994" "1993" "1992" "1991" "1990" "1989" "1988" "1987" "1986" "1985" "1984" "1983" "1982" "1981" "1980" "1979" "1978" "1977" "1976" "1975" "1974" "1973" "1972" "1971" "1970" "1969" "1968" "1967" "1966" "1965" "1964" "1963" "1962" "1961" "1960" "1959" "1958" "1957" "1956" "1955" "1954" "1953" "1952" "1951" "1950" "1949" "1948" "1947" "1946" "1945" "1944" "1943" "1942" "1941" "1940" "1939" "1938" "1937" "1936" "1935" "1934" "1933" "1932" "1931" "1930" "1929" "1928" "1927" "1926" "1925" "1924" "1923" "1922" "1921" "1920" "1919" "1918" "1917" "1916" "1915" "1914" "1913" "1912" "1911" "1910" "1909" "1908" "1907" "1906" "1905" "1904" "1903" "1902" "1901"]<br></div>
```

Any idea why validation does not work?

For some reason all other elements are required but DoB does not work. It can go through without validation. I know its a bit hacky but it seems to work design-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert a "label" option to make user select. Check [their document](https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/).

```
[select* menu-dob-day id:drop_day first_as_label "Select your day of birth*" "1"...
```

or simpler:

```
[select* menu-dob-day id:drop_day include_blank "1"...
```

Insert to month, year field also then you're good to go.